# how to synchronize getter and setter method in c++

Tags: c++, windows

If 2 following methods in same class.

```
  bool CSettings::GetDelayTimer()
  {     
     return m_iTimerDelay;     
  }

  void CSettings::SetDelayTimer(int iTimerdelay)
  {
    m_iTimerDelay = iTimerdelay;
  }
```

In order to synchronize above methods I created following lock/unlock methods.

```
  void CSettings::Lock()
  {
    DWORD dwRet = WaitForSingleObject(m_hSettingsLock, INFINITE);
    if( dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
      return;
  }

  void CSettings::UnLock()
  {
    ReleaseMutex(m_hSettingsLock);
  }
```

how do I synchronize these getter/setter methods using lock/unlock. If I use lock in getter method I don't get chance to unlock as it will return before unlocking.
I mean to say : 
Lock(); return m_iTimerDelay; UnLock();
Is it gonna work?
Applying Lock/UnLock to setter is not a problem.

Any Idea to synchronize these methods?

Regards,
Khurram.

Comment: Why do people answer questions in comments? Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: Usually it's because they don't have sufficient time to write a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization#C.2B.2B_example). Make an object whose constructor acquires the lock and whose destructor releases it. Then you can just do:

```
{
    ScopedLock f(m_hSettingsLock);
    return m_iTimerDelay;
}
```

Let `ScopedLock::~ScopedLock` release the lock.

Alternatively, the most likely inferior:

```
{
    Lock();
    bool ret = m_iTimerDelay;
    Unlock();
    return ret;
}
```

Note that in both cases the returned value can be stale.

Comment: Later is better if you have many calls to getter, because that will save you constructor & destructor calls. On the other hand first one is reusable.

Comment: @fadedreamz If your compiler won't optimize them out, throw it away and get a real compiler. This is a common pattern and any compiler that couldn't optimize it would be, in my opinion, a toy.

Comment: I didn't think about compiler optimization. My bad, but I am also curious about the optimization process on this piece of code ... can you point me on some reference link?